есть ли в C# функция похожая на функцию std::cin.tie()
есть ли в C# функция похожая на функцию std::cin.tie() или похожая для ускорения чтения с консоли?

Console.In и Console.Out возвращают TextReader и TextWriter. / Приведите больше информации. Как и что хотите читать.

Что значит ускорения? Зачем? Где у вас медленно? Задачу озвучьте.

Также смотрите методы Console.OpenStandardOutput и Console.OpenStandardInput. Вообще, обычно к виндовой консоли претензии по скорости вывода. Она медленная, потому что синхронизированная. См. https://stackoverflow.com/q/29920056/5045688 как ускориться.

Если вопрос как добиться 100500 FPS при полной перерисовке консоли, то самое молниеносно быстрое - это прямо в графический буфер консоли писать, посредством грамотного использования WinAPI методов kernel32.dll WriteConsoleOutputCharacter и WriteConsoleOutputAttribute.
